# File not found error even when my file is there

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I am reading a file in my assignment from class. However, when i compile it, fileNotFound error. (No such file or directory) is displayed. I don't understand why its there because my file is in the same folder as my program. I have also tried changing my extension to .dat, but the error still shows. Here is my code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("measurements.txt"));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        .... // continues      
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error!\nFile not found.");
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error ");
}
```

Comment: You should tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: Do a check for your current directory ... it might not be what you think it is ... System.getProperty("user.dir")

Comment: Seems it uses Java language. To get rid of this error, try to use absolute path to your file instead of considering relative path. I mean: FileReader("/home/user/measurements.txt")...

Comment: Check RW access to that file, happened to me once.

Comment: I doubt you're getting a FileNotFoundException at compile time...

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to provide absolute path of file in following line. File reader need absolute path to read a file.

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("measurements.txt"));
```

However there are some other alternatives to read file from relative path for example if you have created file in src/classes folder then you can read the file as follows.

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        Level.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("measurements.txt")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give absolute path like in windows C:/somefolder/measurements.txt or in linux /home/user/measurements.txt

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/measurements.txt"));
```

It will work ...

As you giving relative path it should work but  I doubt that you are running your program from a different directory than your java file and file you are reading .

Answer (score 0):

It is because the file doesn't has permission to read. go to file properties and give read/write permission
And be sure to give absolute path to the file

Answer (score -1):

Didn't you need to write the full path or at least the relative path, not only the file name?

Comment: Not an answer - more appropriate as a comment